# Sonar rules - method name too long

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

I want to define a Sonar rule that avoid a method name specified in an interface from having a length greater than 25 and at the same time if the method is defined in the interface it has to start with the word "run". I have been trying to figure out how to do it but I do not know exactly how to do it. I think that the it should be a checkstyle rule but I do not know exactly how to define it.

Can somebody help me to define it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more difficult than it seems at first glance. Of course the [MethodName](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#MethodName) check is the check to use, but the problem is to restrict the check to methods defined in interfaces.

The *MethodName* check should be configured like this:

```xml
<module name="MethodName">
    <property name="id" value="methodNameInInterface"/>
    <property name="format" value="^run(?=.{0,22}$)[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
</module>
```

Note the `id` property, which is used to identify this rule in the suppression filter config, as you will have other *MethodName* checks defined. This is the easy part.

In order to suppress the generated warning for all methods but the ones defined in interfaces, you can use a [suppression filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#SuppressionFilter). But this will only work if you have a naming convention for interfaces (like, a common `IF` postfix). If you don't have such a naming convention, then you will have to either:

- implement a [custom filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingfilters.html) that can filter messages based on the type of file, or
- implement a [custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), possibly as a subclass of *MethodName*, which adds an option to restrict the warnings to certain types of files.

If you have a naming convention for interfaces, you can configure the suppression filter like this:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress id="methodNameInInterface" files="(?!IF)..\.java$"/>
</suppressions>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Thomas. I have some kind of naming convention because the name of the interface will have four letters followed by a "U" and finishing with 3 characters/numbers. On the other hand the implementation wil have the same structure but with an impl at the end. Therefore I think that it could be sufficient with a filter as follows: files="\D{4}U\w{3}.java$" Am I right? Furthermore is it necessary to indicate the package name? Thanks again your help

Comment: Yes, that should be good. Note that `\w` includes underscores. The package name *can* be used, but it is not needed.

Comment: I just noticed a mistake in the suppression regex. Corrected above. In your case, you'd need it to be `(?!\D{4}U\w{3}).{8}.java$`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hello Thomas! I have been doing some test and I think that for the case that I want to test it is better to define the filter like this ^([A-Z]{4}[U]{1}[A-Z0-9]{3}).java$ What do you think? Do you think it could fail? Can it happens that it detects a class which has the previous pattern as a substring? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: (Note that this should be a separate question.) [Try it out.](http://regex101.com/r/iL2hH4/1) I think you need the opposite, because the suppression filter matches files where the warning should *not* be displayed. Also try my suggestion from above. Keep in mind that the entire path will be matched, not just the simple file name.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I had understand it in the wrong way. But if I use your suggestion, then the warning will be also launched if I put somthing before the expression, for example iiiiiiAAAAU12E.java Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: (Note that this should be a separate question, as it deals with crafting regexes, not with checking method names in Checkstyle.) Try [to use this](http://regex101.com/r/nH5gE1/1): `(?![\\/]\D{4}U\w{3}).{9}.java$`. The suppression filter matches absolute file paths, not binary class names.